# QGIS split vector layer gives me GPKG files but I need shp files

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, vector, splitting

QGIS 3.6.0

I am new to QGIS software and not very technical on its deep workings. I am trying to split a .shp file using split vector layer. I need .shp file outputs but it auto creates .gpkg files.

I cant seem to find any settings that will change the default from .gpkg to .shp

Comment: you can change default vector output in the processing options tab in Settings. see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/256679/1297

Comment: I'm having the same problem with split vector layer in qgis 3.4.5+ on windows. Since the split vector layer tool saves to a folder rather than an individual file I am unable to specify a format as demonstrated by etrimaille. In the advanced settings there is a "DEFAULT_OUTPUT-VECTOR-LAYER-EXT" option. Changing this option is not working with split vector layer tool either. At the moment I'm at a loss and am writing a python script to try to recover this functionality.

Answer (score 7):

To fix my issue I edited VectorSplit.py located at 
QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis

I reverted the first change here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/8446d3bdf0089cdee6316e40a7cd0047dbf455c1

such that line 111 now reads

```
fName = u'{0}_{1}.shp'.format(baseName, str(i).strip())
```

Answer (score -1):

For this special case of the split vector layer algorithm, **before QGIS 3.10**:

- You need to update the code as mentioned in the other answer.

**Since QGIS 3.10**, the parameter is back and working:
[image]

Source: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/31973

**For usual Processing algorithm, any QGIS version**:

You could let the default output memory layer when you launch the algorithm. And only after your analysis, in your legend, right click on your layer, `export` and then `Save features as`. You can choose the format you want, such as shapefile.
[image: export features as]

Or, you can simply choose the format your want before to run your processing algorithm
[image: save to file]

and choose `Shapefile`
[image: save as shapefile]

Comment: Unfortunately you can not choose the file type in all algorithms, split vector layer is one of it. Here you can only choose an output folder, not the file type.