# Convert shapefile to KML

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, convert, kml

I have one big layer which contains many polygons. This layer is a shapefile and I want to convert it to be many layers, each layer containing one polygon, and those polygon layers should be saved as KML. I have tried to use the tool ''Convert Format'' as I was advised by other people but I can't understand how to make it into KML and all I get is a new layer called ''converted'' and I can't find the difference.

What did I miss?
[image]

The end goal is to have many KML filles in the end, one KML layer per polygon

Comment: How does "save as/export" when you rightclick the layer not suit your needs? Beyond that: Please consult the documentation for the tool: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/ogr_conversion/convertformat.html

Comment: Because I have many layers to do it  so if I gonna do it one by one it's gonna take me few years

Comment: @Reut - Click the ellipses button to the right when saving, you can select the output type.

Comment: @Reut - (_comment based on OP's recent edit_): Ensure each polygon has a unique attribute (you could use the _Field Calculator_ and set an expression like `$rownum`). Then use the **Split vector layer** tool to export each polygon as an individual shapefile. Then use the **Convert format** in batch mode, set the input and output settings and ensure the output type is KML (note: make use of _Autofill_ property to make your life easy).

Comment: @Joseph, what is the Autofill property?

Comment: @Reut - If you run the tool as a batch process (right-clicking it from the _Processing Toolbox_), you can have it set the input and output paths automatically.

Comment: when I used the split vector layers, each layer got name. is there any way to keep those names when I save it as kml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comment, you need to choose the format you want to convert to by choosing the Save to file option in the 'Converted section, and then picking the format you want to convert to.

[image: Convert format]

You need to end up with a GDAL command that begins with

```
ogr2ogr -f "LIBKML"
```

You have to do this because the default option for this tool as per the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalconvertformat) is save to shapefile

Answer (score 5):

### How to split a vector layer *and* convert it to KML format

The `split vector layer` tool creates geopackage files by default. If this is a process you do frequently, it may be worthwhile to follow the steps [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/317169/81764) to change the output setting for this tool. Otherwise, it takes two steps to split your layer and convert it to KML.

1. Split the layer using the `split vector layer` tool, in the Processing Toolbox. Save the split layers to a new folder, which you will delete after the next step. *Don't* import the split layers into your project.
2. Run the GDAL `Convert format` tool in batch processing mode.

   [image]

   Click the ellipsis button (`...`) and choose the option to "Select from file system."

   [image]

   Open the folder you created in step 1. Select all the split files in the folder. They will load into the batch processing window.

Once step 2 is complete, delete the folder you created in step 1.

Comment: Best answer, using nothing but built-in tools.

Answer (score 3):

You can create separate polygons in KML format directly when using the Convert format tool without using other tools as follows and using an example:

- This is a grid shapefile with 20 polygons

[image]

- Use Convert format tool from `Processing toolbox -> GDAL -> Vector Conversion -> Convert format`
- Select Input Polygon shapefile (20 polygons above in this example)
- Select iterator (green arrow) beside the input Layer
- Under `Converted`, click on the three dots `...` to give a name to the output KML file (Polygon in this example) and select `KML` format, then save. See the image below.

[image]

- Run the tool. Here is the output

[image]

- Each file of them is composed of one polygon in KML format:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that I think will work for you:

1. Go to Plugins and install the `mmqgis-plugin`

[image: Mmqgis plugin]

2. Use the plugins' `combine` function to `merge` your layers.
3. `Save/export` the combined layer as `KML`.

Comment: this is good but the problem is that at the beggining I have very big layer with many plots and I want to get in the end all those plots, seperated, each one saved as KML. i'll also edit my question for it to be clear